# Trying to understand CVE-2023-3824

Tags: php, security, exploit, phar

I recently came across CVE-2023-3824, which has been rated as critical with a score of 9.8. This vulnerability constitutes a Remote Code Execution (RCE) and does not require any user interaction. The description for this CVE is as follows:

"In PHP versions 8.0.* before 8.0.30, 8.1.* before 8.1.22, and 8.2.* before 8.2.8, when loading a phar file and reading PHAR directory entries, insufficient length checking may lead to a stack buffer overflow, potentially resulting in memory corruption or RCE."

Now, my question is: how can an HTTP request sent to a website or web server trigger the loading of a phar file and cause this vulnerability? Should there be a specific portion of the code that allows this vulnerability to occur? I'm curious because this bug's presence led to the downfall of the largest ransomware gang.

Additionally, there was a GitHub issue that further confused me. Here is the link for reference:

[Git issue](https://github.com/php/php-src/security/advisories/GHSA-jqcx-ccgc-xwhv)

[NVD post](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-3824)

Comment: _"how can an HTTP request sent to a website or web server trigger the loading of a phar file and cause this vulnerability?"_ It can't, generally. Sites aren't normally ever going to process PHAR files, and aren't normally ever going to contain the source code to do so. You can't just arbitrarily cause `phar_dir_read()` to execute unless the server already has another vulnerability.

Comment: In other words, this vulnerability probably only affects scripts that are already using the PHAR functions.

Comment: Google the CVE ID and "PoC" or "proof of concept" and you'll get a number of results including: https://github.com/php/php-src/security/advisories/GHSA-jqcx-ccgc-xwhv